# Pip install local repository with #egg

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, egg

I have a pip install command `pip install -e git+git@REPO_PATH#egg=LIBNAME[name1,name2]` 
 I would like to do this from a local respository instead of doing git clone, I am struggling finding the local equivalent command for this and read documentation at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/ 
Tried `pip install -e LOCAL_REPO_PATH --egg LIBNAME[name1, name2]` but that fails with `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement LIBNAME[name1, name2] (from versions: )` 
 Using python2.7 and pip 9.0.1 ( old versions I know but need to use 2.7 bcz project is in 2.7 )

Comment: `pip install -e 'LOCAL_REPO_PATH[name1,name2]'` I believe is the syntax

Comment: oh. This worked :D